# How do I create my own custom Roles for Reporting against SSAS and associate it with a role in Dynamics AX?

Tags: ssas, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

Dynamics AX comes with 25 predefined roles in the Default Analysis Database. 
How do I create my own and associate this new Role with a Role within Dynamics AX?

I know the create Role wizard in SQL Server Management Studio, but I don't know how to tie my customer userprofile to Roles in my Analysis Database.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are no relations besides the naming. Conceptually the Roles are associated, but you are free to create Roles in SSAS independent of whatever Roles that exists in AX. So there you have it. It wasn't harder than that.